# How does Visual Studio's Thread Window Identify the "Main Thread'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, multithreading, debugging

I am likely missing something obvious, but humor me...

I always like to name the important threads in my apps as it is useful with debugging/logging etc. If you query the main thread's name via `Thread.CurrentThread.Name` at program startup you will get back `null`. As such, I always ensure that the first thing that happens is that the main thread (and any other relevent threads) get assigned a nice meaningful name for future reference.

I never really gave it much thought until today, but when looking at the Threads window in Visual Studio (before any thread names are assigned etc), a special category 'Main Thread' is assigned as well as a psuedo name that also reads "Main Thread" (but that isn't the actual thread name).

From a managed perspective, .NET doesn't expose anything meaningful on either `System.Threading.Thread` or `System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread` that identifies an application's main thread (at least that I could see). I looked at the list of [Windows Process and Thread Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and again, I didn't see anything obvious (perhaps OpenThread?).

Curious if anyone knows how the Threads window assigns the special category "Main Thread"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debugger starts debugging with CreateProcess using the DEBUG_PROCESS option.  The main thread's handle is returned in PROCESS_INFORMATION.hThread so no guessing there.  Attaching is a bit trickier, presumably the first CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT notification its sees from WaitForDebugEvent after attaching with DebugActiveProcess().

The [source code](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=38449a42-6b7a-4e28-80ce-c55645ab1310&displaylang=en) for MDbg is available if you want to take a closer look.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; thanks for the info. The SourceCode is definitely interesting.

Comment: The CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT notifications are asynchronous.  I'm not sure the order of delivery is guaranteed.  The info returned by CreateProcess makes sense, though.