How to correctly determine a process' primary (first) thread
There have been many questions about how to identify the process' main thread. A common answer was that there is no "main" thread and all threads are equivalent.
This is an incorrect and highly theoretical answer. The main thread is the first one created by the process. The Visual Studio debugger in the Threads window can somehow distinguish the main thread from the others. And I want to know, at the time of loading the statically linked DLLs (before WinMain), how the debugger does it. Ultimately, I want to get the ID of this thread.
EDIT: As @IInspectable stated, "While there is a thread that ultimately initializes a process that thread doesn't have any distinguishing features. It can terminate at any point while other threads owned by the process continue executing". I know this and I completely agree with it. But I'm dealing with a giant 30-years-old product consisting of several interacting EXEs and several hundreds DLLs. And many different DLLs (which know nothing about each other and about EXEs) have pieces of code that are only allowed to run on the main thread. Otherwise the application crashes. You can repeat many times that this is a very bad design, but this is what I have and I can't do anything about it. And this is what I call "practice", as opposite to abstractly true but useless statements.
Therefore, our product needs a sort of service that tells whether the current thread is the process' primary thread. So I chose a very basic DLL that is statically linked to all EXEs and almost all other DLLs, and implemented such a "service" there exactly as described in @MSalters answer.
This worked well until recently I started receiving complaints  from developers in another country's office, that the chosen DLL was being loaded on a worker thread (causing the application to crash). We cannot reproduce this phenomenon in our office, and so all I have are snapshots of the debugger's thread window. Below is the one of them; if it tells something to somebody, I would be very happy to know.


Well, which is it? Incorrect? or 'highly theoretical'? You can't have it both ways.

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891303/how-does-visual-studios-thread-window-identify-the-main-thread

@user207421 I know that all threads have the same internal structure and are treated the same by the OS. So from a theoretical POV they are indistinguishable. But when it comes to using threads, the primary thread is often special. In our application, which contains probably 15 millions lines of C++ and C# code, some parts are only allowed to be executed on the main thread. Do not ask me why -- this is a fact.
I would also like to know, why my question was downvoted.

"There is no main thread" is the correct answer. While there is a thread that ultimately initializes a process that thread doesn't have any distinguishing features. It can terminate at any point while other threads owned by the process continue executing. The more relevant question here is: Why do you need to know? What are you planning to do with that information?

This is an incorrect.. - your statement is incorrect. what is really you need todo ?

@Ilia You haven't answered my question.

@IInspectable Please read my previous comment to see why I need the main thread ID. And I need this inside a very deep layer of code that knows nothing about, say, the main window, from which I could get such information. Inside a DLL that is used in several different EXEs. So I wanted to encapsulate this information in this DLL. And don't say me about bad design - it's impossible to redesign an application that has 15 million lines of code and was created over 30 years ago.

@RbMm Please see my answer to IInspectable.

@user207421 I think I did. I'm not asking out of theoretical interest. I need to solve a practical problem and I'm limited in the solutions I can use.

@Ilia you can call NtGetNextThread for get handle to currently first thread in your process. or use NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemExtendedProcessInformation or SystemProcessInformation and got list of thread IDs in your process. in your app - first thread and will be "main". despite this is really wrong design. dll is passive code. it export functions and interfaces. and exported code called by another code, on threads which select not you. dll usually not care on which thread it code run and not select this.

I need to solve a practical problem - better you ask about this problem, instead of "main" thread

"How do I identify a particular thread?" is a different question from "How do I find a process' primary thread?". You've asked for the latter but apparently need the former.

Based on your screenshot, some code in your process call LoadLibraryW from another threads. Not system code, but "your" code. Or maybe some components in system ( like av, edr) inject dlls in you code via CreateRemoteThread + LoadLibraryW

I edited the question as required so it is now focuses on my actual problem, and I added all data I have. Therefore I kindly request to reopen the question.

I'm pretty sure the DLL's don't care one iota about the "main" thread - that's not special. However, they probably do care about the GUI thread, which is special. Or worse, GUI threads, considering the apparent mess.

You didn't answer my question as to whether you meant 'incorrect' or 'highly theoretical'. You cannot maintain both these beliefs at the same time in a logical mind. They are mutually contradictory.

@user207421 It is true that I cannot prefer one thread over another, because they are indistinguishable. But it is also true that there exists a thread, known as main, which is the first one created by the process.
Those telling that there is no main thread actually want to impose on me their belief that in a properly designed program, the code should not depend on which thread it is running on. And they are right. But this doesn't help solve my problem. Real life is more complex than binary logic.

@Ilia are you look at all to self screenshot ? threads (2) with LoadLibraryWStub start address - doesn't give you any ideas? this is some external process call CreateRemoteThread with LoadLibraryW as entry point. classic dll injection.

@MSalters You are right, there are many GUI threads. Part of them use MFC, another part - WTL, and yet another part - WPF. As I said, the product is old and huge, this is why such a mix of different technologies.
In theory I could obtain primary thread from the main application window, but this is often needed in DLLs having no access to the main window. I wanted confirmation that my implementation, which actually follows your answer, is correct.

@Ilia: What makes you think that the "MFC main thread" is the same as the "WTL main thread", either is the same as the "WPF main thread", or that any of the three is the first thread in the process? Also, same flawed assumption: Win32 does not have the notion of a main window in an application. And the first window often is a splash screen as the main app is still loading.

@MSalters It is not interesting what could be, interesting only what I have. I have main application window created in WinWain. It doesn't matter that the main window is not the first (due to the splash). All that matters is that the main window belongs to the first thread of the process, which is commonly referred to as the "main" thread. This is common for most Windows applications, at least for old enough, and it's better considering this when answering.

@Ilia: Win32 threads are a Kernel32 thing. Kernel32 does not depend on User32, where CreateWindow lives. You therefore can't call any Kernel32 function to get a thread status and have that depend on User32. And User32.dll isn't that special, it too is loaded like the other DLLs (unlike Kernel32, which is special, and guaranteed to load before your DllMain)

@MSalters "MFC main thread"... "WTL main thread"... "WPF main thread" - there are no such notions. There is the notion of the application main thread - the first one created in the process and executing the WinMain entry point. This thread may perfectly be GUI-less.
I also didn't understand what you meant in your last comment. Of course, I don't call CreateWindow or other User32-specific things from within DllMain.

The debugger can show which thread (if any) originated from the EXE's entrypoint. This entrypoint is not WinMain, because your compiler needs the entrypoint to set up its runtime. That runtime calls your WinMain.
At DLL loading time (i.e. DllMain) your code runs under Loader Lock, and there is very little you can do at this time. But the call to DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH specifically happens on this first thread. So you don't need to do anything to find out this thread. You can safely use TlsAlloc to mark this thread for future use. You can also safely call GetCurrentThreadId since this is a kernel32  function, which is already loaded before DllMain.

But the call to DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH specifically happens on this first thread. - DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH specifically happens on thread, which call LoadLibrary[Ex] (LdrLoadDll) - and this can be any thread. in case linked to exe dll dependencies - yes, "first" thread

@MSalters Oh, thanks God, I got one meaningful response and not just downvotes. Your advice was exactly what I originally implemented, and it worked well until recently, when some developers (oddly enough, not end users) began complaining that on their machines the (statically linked) DLL was being loaded on the worker thread. Browsing the internet, I found that the loader behavior has been changed in Windows 10, so that DLLs can now be loaded on threads from the Thread Pool. This is the main reason for my question.

@Ilia nothing changes in windows 10. Dll entry point always called from thread which begin load dll.

@RbMm I was surprised to hear this from you, after recently seeing your answer to the question "Why are there three unexpected worker threads when I run a Win32 console application?", and also reading this blog.

@RbMm I know that you are an expert; I simply confused because I read two posts about "parallel loading" in Windows 10, and one of these posts is your own. Why are you feel offended instead of explain what I'm missing?

@Ilia DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH always called from thread which begin load dll (direct or indirect). and parallel loader here nothing change. so nothing changed in win 10 here too. answer in wrong in point - But the call to DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH specifically happens on this first thread. - i say about this in first comment.

@RbMm "always called from thread which begin load dll" - but whether that thread is the primary (first) thread of the process? And if it is so, then what a parallel loader is about? I'm talking here about a DLL that is being loaded from the process's import table, there is no any LoadLibrary call.

@RbMm: Note that the question mentions DLL's that are loaded at program startup, i.e. not via LoadLibrary (or delay-loading). The DllMain documentation specifically states that "This call [i.e. DllMain] is made in the context of the thread that caused the process address space to change, such as the primary thread of the process or the thread that called LoadLibrary.". And the latter option does not apply.

@Ilia - how i say - DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH always called from thread which begin load dll (direct or indirect). dll can be start loaded on any thread. parallel loader - do some part of load dll job on worker threads (load additional dl, while resolve imports) but DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH always called on initial thread. DLL that is being loaded from the process's import table - for this dlls DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH always called on thread, which then call exe entry point ( WinMain or main if you want)

@Ilia DLL's that are loaded at program startup - for this dlls DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH always called on your "main" thread. and parralel loader not realated here in any case

@Ilia - question mentions DLL's that are loaded at program startup - vs And I want to know, at DLLs loading time (before WinMain) not the best how you say this ( before WinMain). in this case you really can simply save current thread id. but very interesting for what ? you you later plan use this from dll

@RbMm I explained the reason and described the actual problem in the edit of my question. I would be grateful if you look at it. I also requested to reopen the question.

@Ilia i not view where you describe actual problem.
